# MvcContrib MenuBuilder with Razor view engine

Tags: razor, mvccontrib

The below code (inside a .cshtml file) causes the menu to render outside of the flow of the document i.e. The first lines in the source above the html tag

```
@{
    Html.Menu(
        Menu.Begin(new[]
                        {
                            Menu.Link(Url.Action("action1", new { controller="controller" }), "Action1"),
                            Menu.Link(Url.Action("action2", new { controller="controller" }), "Action2")
                        }));
}
```

Yet in a webforms project, the following works:

```
<% Html.Menu(
        Menu.Begin(new[]
                        {
                            Menu.Link(Url.Action("action1", new { controller="controller" }), "Action1"),
                            Menu.Link(Url.Action("action2", new { controller="controller" }), "Action2")
                        })); %>
```

I believe the two syntaxes should result in the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Menu(
        Menu.Begin(new[]
                        {
                            Menu.Link(Url.Action("action1", new { controller="controller" }), "Action1"),
                            Menu.Link(Url.Action("action2", new { controller="controller" }), "Action2")
                        }))
```

That should work.. Removing the braces {}

Answer (score 0):

You should think of @( ) being the equivalent of <%= %> rather than @{ } when converting to razor.